# Running Regression estimation using rstan

Tags: r, bayesian, stan, rstan

I am using `stan` through `rstan` package in R. Below is my model. This model has an interaction term as `X1 * X2`

```r
        library(rstan)
    library(bayesrules)
    data(weather_WU); head(weather_WU, 20)
    
    MCMC_Regression_Model =
        "
        data {
            int<lower = 0> n;
            vector[n] Y;
            vector[n] X1;
            vector[n] X2;
        }
        parameters {
            real beta0;
            real beta1;
            real beta2;
            real beta3;
            real<lower = 0> sigma;
        }
        model {
            Y     ~ normal(beta0 + beta1 * X1 + beta2 * X2 + 
                      beta3 * X1 .* X2, sigma);
            beta0 ~ normal(25, 5);
            beta1 ~ normal(0, 37.52);
            beta2 ~ normal(0, 0.82);
            beta3 ~ normal(0, 0.55);
            sigma ~ exponential(0.13);
        }
        "
    MCMC_Regression_SIMU =
        stan(model_code = MCMC_Regression_Model,
                data = list(n = nrow(weather_WU), 
                            Y = weather_WU[['temp9am']],    
                            X1 = weather_WU[['location']], 
                            X2 = weather_WU[['humidity9am']]
                        ),
                chains = 4,        
                iter = 5000 * 2,    
                seed = 84735
            )
```

With this, I get below error

```r
    Error in mod$fit_ptr() : 
      Exception: variable does not exist; processing stage=data 
      initialization; variable name=X1; base type=vector_d  (in  
      'model1e9057045768_9ae288549657a6a89a994b0dc81a6d24' at 
        line 5)
```

This error says that `variable does not exist` but, variable is pretty much there in definition.

I will really appreciate if you could help me to correctly run above code.

Comment: Your Q was closed because it is considered off-topic:  Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen  Thanks. But surely I did not ask how a software works. I have provided a specific example and software failed to run. I just asked for help how to resolve such problem if anyone have experienced such. There are similar questions everywhere in StackExchange. I am still not sure why my question was singled out and forcibly closed. It is nothing but manipulation. I dont think it is right attitude towards members

Comment: Stackexchange (SE) is a network consisting of different sites, with somewhat different rules. Questions about why some code (with runnable minimal example) do not work as expected if for SO (stackoverflow), not for Cross Validated (CV). If you want we can migrate it there for you!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen thanks. please migrate to right forum. I strongly believe this is honest and genuine question/post. And I really need help

Answer (score 0):

I got basically the same error (after re-installing `rstan`) - different hash, but same words. So tried to do this directly in `cmdstanr`. (Although I don't use Stan very much, it's my recent experience that the direct R-to-Stan interface via `rstan` has been getting extremely flaky of late.

```r
## if necessary:
install.packages("cmdstanr",
        repos = c("https://mc-stan.org/r-packages/",
                                       getOption("repos")))
library(cmdstanr)
set_cmdstan_path("~/.cmdstan/cmdstan-2.27.0/") ## idiosyncratic/ if necessary

writeLines(MCMC_Regression_Model, con="tmpreg.stan")
mod <- cmdstan_model("tmpreg.stan")

fit <- mod$sample(
         data = list(n = nrow(weather_WU), 
                     Y = weather_WU[['temp9am']],    
                     X1 = weather_WU[['location']], 
                     X2 = weather_WU[['humidity9am']]
                     ),
         chains = 4,
         iter_warmup = 5000,
         iter_sampling = 5000,
         seed = 84735
         )
```

Abbreviated session info:

```
R Under development (unstable) (2021-09-23 r80950)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Pop!_OS 20.10    

other attached packages:
[1] bayesrules_0.0.1     rstan_2.21.2         ggplot2_3.3.5       
[4] StanHeaders_2.21.0-7 cmdstanr_0.4.0
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please help to set up `set_cmdstan_path("~/.cmdstan/cmdstan-2.27.0/")` I use Mac and Windows but I failed to find that path in both OSs. What is the absolute path?

Comment: I'm not sure, it will vary by machines.  You can probably do a search for `cmdstan-2.27.0` on your machine and find it ...